# How to slice an array with wrapping?

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

I have this array of days:

```js
const days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']
```

I need a function that can capture all days between (inclusive) 2 specified days.  For instance:

```js
function getDaysBetween(day1, day2) {
  return days.slice(days.indexOf(day1), days.indexOf(day2) + 1);
}
```

This works:

```js
getDaysBetween('Monday', 'Thursday');
// ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday']
```

But this doesn't:

```js
getDaysBetween('Saturday', 'Monday');
// []
// should be ['Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday']
```

It returns an empty array if the index of the first day is greater than the index of the second day.

How can I fix this function to produce the results I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach with an adjustment for the end index.

```js
function getDaysBetween(day1, day2) {
    const
        start = days.indexOf(day1),
        end = days.indexOf(day2) + 1;

    return [...days, ...days].slice(start, end < start ? end + days.length : end);
}

const days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];


console.log(getDaysBetween('Monday', 'Thursday')); // ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday']
console.log(getDaysBetween('Saturday', 'Monday')); // ['Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday']
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Why `var` though?

Answer (score 1):

When the second day index is less than the first day index, you can concat from the first index onwards, and until the second index.

```
function getDaysBetween(day1, day2) {
  let day1Index = days.indexOf(day1);
  let day2Index = days.indexOf(day2);
  if (day2Index < day1Index) {
    return days.slice(day1Index, days.length).concat(days.slice(0, day2Index + 1));
  } else {
    return days.slice(days.indexOf(day1), days.indexOf(day2) + 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A short solution based on the two weeks arrangement and the second argument of the `Array.indexOf`.

*(I edited my first answer completely. This is another approach.)*

```js
const days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']


function getDaysBetween(day1, day2) {

  let twoWeeks = [...days, ...days];  
   return twoWeeks.slice(twoWeeks.indexOf(day1), twoWeeks.indexOf(day2, twoWeeks.indexOf(day1)) + 1 );
}


console.log(getDaysBetween('Monday', 'Thursday'));
console.log(getDaysBetween('Saturday', 'Monday'));
```

Comment: I rewrote your third line like this because it looks cooler: `d1 > d2 && ([d2, d1] = [d1, d2]);`

Comment: this does not work. it returns `["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]` for the second.